# Can you confirm 2 simple statements about vaporization?

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

Vaporization is an interesting engineering subject, but unfortunately much about it has always been unclear to me.

Recent research of mine has brought my mind to link *vapor pressure* to *boiling* and *partial pressure* to *evaporating*. So I would just like to confirm the following two understandings of mine:

1. **VAPOR PRESSURE** is the pressure needed to "mechanically" keep a liquid from **BOILING**. The composition of the air exerting the pressure doesn't matter.
2. When an evaporating substance's **PARTIAL PRESSURE** equals its **VAPOR PRESSURE**, "statistically" it stops **EVAPORATING**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of the technical terms **vapor pressure**, **boiling** and **partial pressure**.

- **Vapor pressure** or better **equilibrium vapor pressure** is the pressure at which an equilibrium is reached between evaporation and condensation at the liquid surface. Usually it is a function of liquid temperature. E.g. water has a vapor pressure of about 0.03 bar at 25°C. Thus, if the steam pressure in the surrounding is below 0.03 bar, more water will evaporate than steam condensates at the water surface. If the steam pressure is above 0.03 bar, more steam will condense at the water surface than water evaporates. So far this is not related to boiling.
- **Boiling** occures if the liquid is heated so far that the vapor pressure of the liquid is as high as the ambient pressure. E.g. water at 100°C has a vapor pressure of 1 bar, which is the usual ambient pressure. So at a surface of hot water at 100°C the steam pressure totally replaces the ambient air and the steam is transported away from the surface. This strong evaporation process is called boiling.
- **Partial pressure** is not related to evaporation processes at all. If you describe air as a mixture of oxygen and nitrogen the total pressure $P_t$ is just the sum of the partial pressures of oxygen $P_{oxygen}$ and nitrogen $P_{nitrogen}$: $P_t = P_{oxygen} + P_{nitrogen}$. Both oxygen and nitrogen are non-condensable gases under standard conditions. This concept applies for any gas mixture also without condensating gases.

Coming back to your statements:

1. This one is wrong. **Vapor pressure** is a physical property of a liquid at a given temperature. As described above it is the pressure at which condensation and evaporation are in equilibrium. So far it is not related to boiling at all.
2. This one is right. If the steam pressure in the ambient atmosphere is equal to the vapor pressure, condensation and evaporation are in equilibrium and one could say evaporation has stopped. But, be aware that the term **partial pressure** is not related to evaporation processes only, because also non-condensable gases have a partial pressure in a gas mixture.

Comment: Thank you, I understand and appreciate your answer completely! I'll just ask you to take another look at my point 1 as far as the following goes: even if "vapor pressure" is not DEFINED by what I said, is it right to say "IF ambient pressure (air composition doesn't matter) LESS THAN vapor pressure THEN boil"?

Comment: Yes, this statement is right.

Answer (score 1):

I would like this to be a comment to previous answer but unfortunately I can't comment on answers yet. I just wanted to explain a bit more what is so special about boiling because I feel like most of us feel that vapor pressure=ambiant pressure being the definition of boiling point is just a theoretical technicality and the fact the bubbles start to appear is a mere unrelated phenomenon, although the explaination is shockingly simple while mind blowing to some people when they hear it for the first time.

Let us redefine boiling as the point where bubbles start to appear in the liquid, like anyone earth minded would. Now what are these bubbles made of? Pure vapor of our liquid, of course, since no air or other ambiant gas could have made it there (in significant proportions). Since it's our only gas in presence in the bubble, than it has to take up all the pressure, which is ambiant pressure+hydrostatic pressure (prolly neglectable). And how could our gas possibly exist at such a pressure? Well only if its vapor pressure is higher than said pressure of course. Well, there you have it: you can only form bubbles in the liquid itself if vapor pressure>ambiant pressure because at some point the gas has to take up all this pressure on its own.

I fell like this is a much more elegant way of explaining boiling rather than just a "strong form of evaporation". Of course this a little storied and not that technical, refer to other sources or the very good previous answers for other details and/or a swers to the other subquestions

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted to know. I'm just mad that I only read it carefully right after coming to the same conclusion on my own. Anyway, thanks for confirming my thought. You are right, it is MUCH MORE ELEGANT and makes MUCH MORE SENSE!